# FB authentication and Load Testing a Facebook application

Tags: facebook, testing, performance-testing

Does Facebook permit developers to use automated tools to authenticate accounts and load test an application prior to launch?  We wanted to use J-meter to access Facebook to authenticate users then generate load against our application. I was under the impression that it was not permitted to use an automation device to access Facebook. Is this permitted using the FB test accounts?

From FB terms of Service: 
"You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our prior permission:

Comment: You already got yourself an answer

Comment: Fabio, I'm not clear. The test user page on facebook says "A test user is a special user account, invisible to "normal" users, which is created on behalf of an app for the purpose of testing that app's Facebook integration. You can use test users for manual or automated testing. Each app can create up to 2000 test users."

What is Facebook's policy on load testing applications where part of the load test may be hitting their servers.  The info I see is a little ambiguous and doesn't speak to any threshold limits for load testing.